# How to prepopulate UserProfile fields in the Django admin?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Prepopulating most model fields in the admin (useful for generating slugs) seems to be straightforward if you use:

```
prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("name",)}
```

But when I use the code below to try to prepopulate a UserProfile field, it gives this error message, even though I clearly have a slug in the UserProfile model.  (It's just looking in the wrong model and I don't know how to fix this...)

ERROR:

> **ImproperlyConfigured at /admin/**
>   'UserProfileAdmin.prepopulated_fields' refers to field 'slug' that is missing from model 'User'.

In settings.py:

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'myapp.UserProfile'
```

In models.py:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50)
```

In admin.py:

```
class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserProfile
    max_num = 1
    can_delete = False

class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [UserProfileInline]
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("name",)}

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserProfileAdmin)
```

Can anyone spot reason for the error here?

Answer (score 2):

`slug` is a  field in `UserProfile`, but the `prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("name",)}` is an attribute of `UserProfileAdmin`, which is applied to `User`.

`prepopulated_fields` triggers some javascript that autogenerates the value of a SlugField out of the values of some other fields *of the same model*. What you are trying is to prepopulate a field of a *different model*. The `UserProfileAdmin` is applied to `User`, the `prepopulated_fields` refers to the field `slug` which is unknown to the model `User`. It is defined in `UserProfile`.

That's why I think that the biggest problem here is the name `UserProfileAdmin` which should rather be `UserAdmin`. Don't confuse the model to which the `prepopulated_fields` is applied with the one that is inlined. Even when there is a OneToOne relation, it still is a different model.

Comment: The slug field is in UserProfile and the name field is in User.  Even if I create or rename the admin classes for each model, that still doesn't get around the problem that I'm trying to base the prepopulated field on a different model.  I get the error message: 'UserAdmin.prepopulated_fields' refers to field 'slug' that is missing from model 'User'.