# django admin - populate field with callable

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I can't find a single example of anyone doing this apart from this example, which doesn't help me other than to know where the code needs to sit.

[How to prepopulate UserProfile fields in the Django admin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014044/how-to-prepopulate-userprofile-fields-in-the-django-admin)

so this is my code

```
class QuoteMaterial(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=255)
    content = models.TextField(_('content'),
                           help_text=_('A static priced item used when doing a job. Selectable when creating a quote. '))
    price = models.DecimalField(_('price'), max_digits=6, help_text="not sure if this is before or after VAT yet", decimal_places=2, default="0.00")

    def get_companies():
        return CompanyProfile.objects.filter(user=request.user)

    company = models.ForeignKey(CompanyProfile, default=get_companies)
```

If its not obvious, im trying in the admin section to populate a dropdown with the available companies that belong to the user that is logged in.

my problem is that i dont know how to pass the request object to "get_companies". anyone know of any examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to do this overriding in your admin class that extends the `ModelAdmin`, not in your class that extends `models.Model`. Specifically, you need to override `formfield_for_foreignkey`.

From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/):

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "car":
            kwargs["queryset"] = Car.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
    return super(MyModelAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

For your case, it would seem like:

```
if db_field.name == "company":
    kwargs['queryset'] = request.user.company_set.all()
```

Comment: I am not sure if the default values on fields is not for already existing model fields. Even if it is, you need to return a field object, and not just a queryset. Another problem with this approach is, as you rightly pointed out, how do you get request inside the model.

Comment: apologies for the rude comment, edit timed out and i walked away after hitting enter on it, didnt realise itd timed out.

i see that i can't do what i want now, i am going to build a frontend for this site, i guess it just means users will be able to see other peoples company names. not an immediate issue i guess.

Comment: finally re-read your solution above, you've hit the nail on the head, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up terms.

"Prepopulating" means to fill in a field from another field. It's not how you filter things for the admin popups, since you aren't actually setting the field, but simply limiting choices and letting the user set the field from those.

Aditionally, the `default` value for a field needs to be a constant, since this is passed down to the database, which can't use a query to set a default.

What you *really* want is something like the `limit_choices_to` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to)) parameter for your `ForeignKey`, but even then, you can't use `request` for this; it has to work using fields in the model. The reason for this is that, if you based it on the user, then some users would be unable to select the current value set by another user. You don't want `company` changing itself when the user just wants to change `content`, for example, just because `user` doesn't yield the current `company` in the filter.